# jquery validator submit behavior

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I have a fairly large input form with a number of ASP.NET Validators on it, most are RegexVlidators. Validators work fine on a client side and they prevent a postback(submit) if needed. But now we have to while still validating and displaying errors just like they used to also have to allow postback. I have to replace my RegexValidators with jquery validator plugin, so my question is: can validator plugin used so it flags and displays errors but does not prevent submit/postback? If not, what can be used for that, other then custom solution)? Typical validator in use looks like this:

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
                                ID = "ContactEMailValidator" 
                                runat = "server" 
                                ControlToValidate = "ContactEMail"
                                ErrorMessage = "Contact Email is not a valid e-mail." 
                                ValidationGroup="WorkflowsAndIneligible"
                                ValidationExpression = "^\s*\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*$"
                                SetFocusOnError = "true">
                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Besides validation it does a number of other things - set focus on offending input control, displays a tabbable error message

Comment: Don't take offense, but I can't understand your question at all. Could you rephrase that more explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the Position Absolute inline validation engine to do something similar. It allows you to have full control over the error messages without preventing postback if needed.

For example you can use the `showPrompt` option to display an error field over a form field, but still allow ajax posting.

```
$('#FormFieldID').validationEngine('showPrompt', 'This a custom error msg', 'error', true)
```

More information here - https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

EDIT: Just a quick example of how you might use this in production -

```
    $('#submitButton').click(function(){
        $form = $('#MyForm');
        $form.validationEngine();
        if($form.validationEngine({returnIsValid:true})){
            $form.submit()
        }
    });
```

That example would block the form submission and you could easily build out/display your errors in an `else` block. If you don't want to block the form submission you can just ignore the if statement and submit the form regardless and build out your errors from `ValidationEngine`. You would need to provide a bit more detail for a specific example though.

Comment: Thanks for reply and an idea. You said it allows ajax posting, will it allow standard ASP.NET posting (submit)? Does it support RegEx validations?

Comment: I'll expand on my example a bit to show you how it could either block or not block a standard submit, and it does in fact support custom regex validation!

Comment: Thanks. Also, do you know by any chance if it allows for warning display customization so it looks like ASP.NET validator message in red text and you can tab onto it(for impaired users)?

Comment: You should be able to easily customize the look of the boxes with css, I'm not certain how you could implement the tabbing but Im sure it could be done.

Comment: Basically all I need is to assign certain css class to that red label.

Comment: You could either modify the class in the template that it comes with or override it in your own css. https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/css/template.css

Comment: Can you set that up so it validates on `blur` of the input control?

Comment: Even if I didn't get the exact answer I was looking for, I appreciate the effort, so I accept